# Effective range for missiles?

Tags: x-rebirth

Ingame encyclopedia lists missiles speed and damage, but not range.

What effective/maximum range have each missile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around in game files, i found, that there is no limit in range, rather in time. Each missile has time limit and selfdestruct when it reached

```
Missile         Damage  Firerate Guided  Lifetime Speed  Acceleration
V Crushers       6000   2.5      0        4       0      375
Meteorites      15000   1.5      0        6       0      175
Constrictors    12500   0.25     0       60       325     90
Starflashes      9000   0.8      1       12       775    270
Sunstalkers     18000   0.6      1       18       550    180
Hellbusters     36000   0.4      1       30       325     90
Astrobees        6000x8 0.3      1       18       350    350
Tristars        36000x3 0.2      1       36       210    210
Novadrones      80000   0.2      0       60      1000     50
```

Using this, i can estimate, that Meteorite and V Crusher missiles have max range about 3km.

With Sunstalker range is near 9km if target is not maneuvering.

Using Novadrones, while boring, allow to reach target in 50km.